# C#: Label Designing for Color Printers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, printing

I'm developing a Label Printing application for our company that will include support for Black & White and Color Printers.

To simplify development on my part, I'm creating a WinForm with various labels on it that I can position, size, and color as needed. If the End User's printer is Non-Color, all Pens and Brushes will be black. Otherwise, I will be setting my drawing colors based on the Label control's color.

I'd like to develop my labels using basic colors that are found in the standard color printer cartridge, so that I don't wind up causing our company to throw away a cartridge simply because Color Tank #2 has run out (trying to reduce waste and help the environment where I can).

What are the Colors in the tanks? Black, Magenta, Yellow, and Cyan?

If I designed my Labels using these four (4) colors, would I be making good use of the color cartridges or should I stick to combination colors like Red, Blue & Green?

I'd be interested in looking at a simple algorithm that calculates how much color is used, too, if someone knows how to do that.

[image: EPSON Cartridge with Black, Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow]

Comment: I'd say it would depend on printer models more than anything. Just printing in black doesn't guarantee you'll only use "black"

Comment: If `PrintPreviewDialog.Document.DefaultPageSettings.Color == true`, then I want to focus on colors that pull equal amounts of Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow. If the Default Page Settings does not support Color, then I will specify in code that all Pens use a Black Brush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

**There is no way to calculate how much of a color is used on a form that I make.**

And...

**There is no way to balance the amount of colors I select for a printout to load balance the ink in the cartridges.**

For now, this is the answer.

If someone can show this to be wrong one day, I'm subscribed for answers, and I'll be happy to mark a solution ...if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much zero control over what color tanks a given printer is going to use.  Especially on a low end printer in which the tanks are merged into a single cartridge.

The problem is that even if your application specifies a pure cyan (for example), then somewhere between the screen ICC profile, printer ICC profile and the print driver this might be interpreted as being not quite cyan and it will subsequently throw in some yellow and magenta for good measure.

Another wrinkle is that printers have between 1 and 8 cartridges depending on brand, type of printer, etc.  So whatever you code today could quite easily be made useless simply by purchasing a different printer.

A better bet here is to tell your company to invest in some printers that don't force you to replace all of the colors just because one ran out.  (hint, stop buying HP).

Comment: Professional photo printers actually have 12 cartridges now!

Comment: This certainly will not see use on a photo printer! However, I would like a way to try and use most of the common colors in the tank.